# Are PIL libraries for Windows and Linux different? PIL Image Filter not working on Rasp Pi

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use the filter FIND_EDGES to get the edges from a picture and it works on my windows PC but when I run the same code on my Raspberry Pi it gives the error that image has wrong mode.

Comment: What kind of image format is it? Some image formats, for example TIFF and JPEG2000, require a third party library to be read. Maybe the library isn't installed on your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Install the external libraries on Raspberry Pi first. See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html for more info.